# is there any documentation for vscode's launch.json? What I found is out of date/missing

Tags: visual-studio-code

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations

For example it all uses node not c/c++ which seems to have some different options. I see things like `"processId": "${command:pickProcess}",` but I don't see any documentation for what other things you could use command for. Can you have a command that picks your executable? Or do you have to have configurations for each executable you might want to debug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hit the same issue and find this thread, VS Code updated the `lanuch.json` attributes docs here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes

Comment: I can't find `pickProcess` on that page.

Answer (score -1):

That is the official documentation for `launch.json` in general. There is also some more C++ specific information in our C++ docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp and https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference

Please report an issue or make a PR to improve the docs if you notice any bugs or think they could be improved: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs

Comment: The term "launch.json" does not appear on that page.

Comment: It links to the debug docs for c++: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference